# An inner product concerning functions from vertices to $\mathbb{C}$ and the normalized Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am reading this paper http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/cheeger.pdf by F.R.K Chung, on the third page, line (1), she talks about the quantity $$\frac{<h, \mathcal{L}h>}{<h,h>}$$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the normalized Laplacian of a simple graph, and $h:V\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a function from $V$ the set of vertices of $G$ to $
\mathbb{C}$.

I am assuming $< , >$ is some inner product. However, which inner product is this? Also, what exactly is $\mathcal{L}h$? Since $\mathcal{L}$ is a $|E|$ by $|V|$ matrix and $h$ is just a function from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}$, I don't see what $\mathcal{L}h$ is supposed to be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any variant of the Laplacian is a $v\times v$ matrix. The inner product is the usual dot product.

Comment: But the usual dot product is defined on vectors, $h$ is not a vector, it's a function on the set of vertices

Comment: A vector is a function on $\{1,...,n\}$; in this case that is the vertex set of the graph.

Comment: I get it now, thank you @ChrisGodsil

Answer (score 0):

The normalized Laplacian matrix $\mathcal{L}(G)$ of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a matrix of order $|V|\times|V|$ and **NOT** $|E|\times|V|$.

Comment: Appreciated. Although this isn't an answer to the question, more of a comment. Thanks anyway.